How to append line which matches pattern to previous line
Attempting to format tcpdump.txt file:

Lines containing date, interface, protocol, etc.
Lines containing network source device.port, destination device.port, flags, etc.
Extra lines (discard)

Input:
2024-10-02,15:23:15.961802,br0,Out,IP,,
device1-LAN.522,>,device2-LAN.56248:,Flags,,
2024-10-02,15:23:16.961821,eth5,Out,IP,,
0x0010:  0034 844a 4000 3f06 8fe9 c0a8 330b acd4  .4.J@.?.....3...
0x0030:  01ff 00ab 0000 0101 080a e9d3 ecca 22d6  ..............".
2024-10-02 15:23:17.389705, eth0,Out, IP,,
device1-LAN.522,>,device2-LAN.56248:,Flags,,
2024-10-02,15:23:18.962931,br0,Out,IP,,
device1-LAN.522,>,device2-LAN.56248:,Flags,,
2024-10-02,15:23:19.962931 eth0  Out
0x0000:  00e0 6715 cf81 08bf b8c9 a448 0800 4500  ..g........H..E.
0x0020:  8708 87ce 01bb 04f8 16eb 3b51 8be8 8018  ..........;Q..

And more lines.
The goal is to append lines containing date, interface, protocol, etc., with lines containing network source device.port, destination device.port, flags, etc.:
Output:
2024-10-02,15:23:15.961802,br0,Out,IP,,device1-LAN.522,>,device2-LAN.56248:,Flags,,
2024-10-02 15:23:17.389705,eth0,Out,IP,,device1-LAN.522,>,device2-LAN.56248:,Flags,,
2024-10-02,15:23:18.962931,br0,Out,IP,,device1-LAN.522,>,device2-LAN.56248:,Flags,,

And more lines.
Is there an awk solution for this type of pattern matching and line appending?

The desired output is confusing. (1) Why LAN..56248? A typo? (there is LAN.56248 in the input). (2) About the line containing 2024-10-02,15:23:17.961821: where did the device… part come from? In the input there is a device… line after 2024-10-02,15:23:17.961821, but I expected it to be assigned to 2024-09-27 11:18:30.389705 that occurs in between. This leads to the next doubt: (3) Why is there no line containing 2024-09-27 in the output? // Please [edit] and clarify. Make sure the example output is exactly what you want to get from the example input you published.

Hi Kamil.  Review and responses appreciated.  Yes, typos on my part copying packet examples and now corrected.

You can grep out the 0x00 lines, strip the new lines with perl, then put back the line breaks, at the date, using sed.
grep -v 0x00 tcpdump.txt | perl -p -e 's/\R//g;' | sed 's/2024/\n2024/g'

You can add | sed '1d' to get rid of the blank lines at the top.
2024-10-02,15:23:17.961802,br0,Out,IP,,device1-LAN.522,>,device2-LAN.56248:,Flags,,
2024-10-02,15:23:17.961821,eth5,Out,IP,,
2024-09-27 11:18:30.389705, eth0,Out, IP,,device1-LAN.522,>,device2-LAN.56248:,Flags,,
2024-10-02,15:23:17.962931,br0,Out,IP,,device1-LAN.522,>,device2-LAN.56248:,Flags,,


Hi JayCravens.  Several learning opportunities for me (I've used grep, sed, and perl individually but not piped together) , solution works, and review/response appreciated! :-)
